# Updating an instance of an already stored struct?

Tags: solidity, contract-development, contract-design, remix

How can I update/change the values of a stored struct instance?

as an example: Let's say I've already deployed a chapter with the content written in a particular color. Later it turns out that I want to use a different color and therefore need to update the array of the already stored struct instance. How can I now modify the color of the existing stored struct instance to contain the new color?

```
contract NewBook {

    struct ChapterData {
        // string chapterID;
        string title;
        string color;
        uint pages;
    }

    struct BookData {
        // string bookID;
        ChapterData[] chapters;
    }

    mapping(bytes32 => BookData) books; // bookId => BookData

    function addChapter(bytes32 _bookID, string memory title, string color, uint pages) public {
        ChapterData memory c = ChapterData({
            title: title,
            color: color,
            pages: pages
        });
        books[_bookID].chapters.push(c);
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you need the reference of the book and then you can get one `chapters` by passing the index of it (`uint256 chapter`).

Try with this:

```
pragma solidity ^0.5.0;

contract NewBook {

    struct ChapterData {
        // string chapterID;
        string title;
        string color;
        uint pages;
    }

    struct BookData {
        // string bookID;
        ChapterData[] chapters;
    }

    mapping(bytes32 => BookData) books; // bookId => BookData

    function addChapter(bytes32 _bookID, string memory title, string memory color, uint pages) public {
        ChapterData memory c = ChapterData({
            title: title,
            color: color,
            pages: pages
        });
        books[_bookID].chapters.push(c);
    }

    function changeColor (bytes32 _bookID, uint256 chapter, string memory color) public {
        ChapterData storage _chapter = (books[_bookID]).chapters[chapter];
        _chapter.color = color;
    }

    function numChapters (bytes32 _bookID) public view returns (uint256) {
        return books[_bookID].chapters.length;
    }

    function getChapterIndex (bytes32 _bookID, string memory title) public view returns (uint256) {
        for (uint i=0; i < books[_bookID].chapters.length; i++) {
            if( keccak256(abi.encodePacked(books[_bookID].chapters[i].title)) == keccak256(abi.encodePacked(title))){
                return i;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I see, is there an easy way to find the index position?

Comment: @NowsyMe I don't think so with the current implementation. Maybe you could implement a chapter counter/number per book or something like this.

Comment: would it make sense to use a mapping to do this? i.e. every time you add a struct to an array, then map the structID of the struct to the length of the array at given time of addition. Then one could have a key-pair overview (bytes 32 => uint) of all the structs and their index position in the array.

Comment: @NowsyMe It's a possible solution but keep in mind that you will have two different IDs: `bookID` and `chapterID`.

Comment: it makes sense to have two ids when you deal with objectives that should be updateable for me

Comment: @NowsyMe Yes, I'm not saying it doesn't make sense but take it into account. I've updated my answer in which you can get the index of a chapter using the title and the bookID. I'm not a fan of loops but maybe could help you as an alternative. I've tested with some examples but probably the code can be improved.